# Distance between the player and another object Unity

Tags: unity

Edit:
I want to find the distance between the player another  object. How do I do that?

this is what I tried:

```
public GameObject other;


void Update()
{

    float dist = Vector3.Distance(other.transform.position, transform.position);

    print("distance " + dist)


}
```

which didn't seem to work

Comment: what is `other`?

Comment: Do not edit your question in a manner that changes it into something else. If you have another question, ask it as another one.

Comment: @S. Tarık Çetin I am sorry but last time I did that they '-1' it for duplication even though it was different.

Comment: @SP. it's a GameObject (just edited)

Comment: What is currently happening? No output at all???

Comment: It does have an output, but it does not change when the object comes closer.

Comment: @AJ123 i see it's working. value changes when the `other` object moves. have you assigned the `other` object correctly in the script holding object's in inspector. you may have assigned `another` not moving object.

Comment: @AJ123 You are not making any sense. If the question you will post would be a duplicate then it means they are the same question, then why bother editing at the first place? And I saw that "last time", you literally post two identical questions, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that task, you can use [BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) or [PolygonCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html).
Attach it to both objects, but make it 5 pixels larger for the first object.

Then write code, that kills the object, in the [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) / [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) event handlers.

To destroy the object you can use method [Object.Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html), just pass the desired gameObject reference to it.

Here's the reference materials:
[BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html)

Also, you can cast rays of limited length, how to do so described in the following link:

[How to cast ray2d in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

Also, I strongly advice you to learn through this section and watch all the materials, because what you've asked is really basic question, you should at least watch the tutorials in the learn section on Unity site, so you won't ask the questions like this in the future.

[Here it is, please watch it](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

Comment: But I want the first object to be able to overlap the second object, and a second later destroy it. Sorry I wasn't clear before

Comment: I don't want collision, I want position. Sorry if it was unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can measure squared distances:

```
var sqrMagn = (target.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;

if(sqrMagn <= squaredTriggerDistance)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Change `squaredTriggerDistance` to a value you want.

Comment: should I add rigidbody2d instead of target?

Comment: @AJ123 No, that's a `transform` referance. But if you are asking this question, I suggest you to abort what you are doing now and return to tutorials. When I started Unity I was spending %80 of my time reading manual and watching tutorials.

Comment: Target is not a thing in the c# script. I think you gave me something from a js script

Comment: yeah I just checked It is something from a js script. Can you please do this in a c# scipt

Comment: It's your job to adopt the techniques given to you to your own code. It's not nice to ask people to do your work for you.

Comment: @AJ123 Well... Target is supposed to be a variable holding the target gameobject's transform. I thought you could figure it out yourself.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I already tried it myself but was unable to do so. After posting the question I kept trying to do it myself. I just added what I tried.